# How to fix Parrot OS Installation interrupt? - common_interrupt: 1.55 No irq handler for vector

Tags: linux, terminal, error-handling, interrupt, parrotsec

I was trying to install Parrot OS installation. But it appears the interrupt message if I install and it will stuck on the terminal

I already Flashed parrot os using balena etcher and after that I tried to install using Try/Install button on Parrot OS and it will appear this interrupt and will stuck forever

`0.006525] __common_interuppt: 1.55 No irq handler for vector`

It keep saying that interrupt 3x but 1.55, 2.55 and 3.55

Please help me to install Parrot Os Security. Thank you

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405604/how-to-fix-this-error-no-irq-handler-for-vector A few ideas to consider except the one with zero votes that is just dumb. That said the error by itself shouldn't prevent the installation. It seems the live session can't run the graphical environment (the error message is just the last thing it logged before getting stuck but isn't related with it). If you have a safe graphics option or similar that's what you should try.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I already did update my bios but the issue is still there. IOMMU doesn't supported to my laptop that's why it's not showing IOMMU